# How can I add line break in userform?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using "script app" from google sheets and I need to allow line break in the "userform" that I have created, I will use this to feed data to my google sheet and some of the items need multiple lines in the same cell.
 Is there anyway I can do that?

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHdRy.jpg)

[EXAMPLE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGAsF.jpg)

CODE

```
function showAdicionarClienteHTML() {

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("AdicionarClienteHTML");

  var html = template.evaluate();
  html.setTitle("ADICIONAR CLIENTE").setHeight(800).setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Adicionar novo cliente:");
  //.showModalDialog(html, "Adicionar novo cliente:");
  //.showSidebar(html);

}

function appendData(data){

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Clientes");
  ws.appendRow([data.name,data.login,data.sninv,data.numero,data.sndtl,data.tele,data.regiao]);

}
```

HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
       <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
            <input id="nome" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="nome">Nome</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">mail_outline</i>
          <input id="login" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="login">E-Mail ou Login</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">select_all</i>
            <input id="sninv" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="sninv">S/N do Inversor</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">format_list_numberedl</i>
            <input id="numero" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="numero">Numero do Inversor</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">select_all</i>
            <input id="sndtl" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="sndtl">S/N do Datalogger</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">phone_in_talk</i>
            <input id="tele" type="tel" class="validate">
            <label for="tele">Telefone</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">explore</i>
            <input id="regiao" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="regiao">Região</label>
          </div>
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" id="btn">Adicionar
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
      </div><!--END ROW -->
    </div><!--END CONTAINER -->

     <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

     <script>

     var nameBox = document.getElementById("nome");
     var loginBox = document.getElementById("login");
     var sninvBox = document.getElementById("sninv");
     var numeroBox = document.getElementById("numero");
     var sndtlBox = document.getElementById("sndtl");
     var teleBox = document.getElementById("tele");
     var regiaoBox = document.getElementById("regiao");

     document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord); 

     function addRecord(){

      var name = nameBox.value;
      var login = loginBox.value;
      var sninv = sninvBox.value;
      var numero = numeroBox.value;
      var sndtl = sndtlBox.value;
      var tele = teleBox.value;
      var regiao = regiaoBox.value;
      if(name.trim().length == 0 || login.trim().length == 0 || sninv.trim().length == 0 || numero.trim().length == 0 || sndtl.trim().length == 0 || tele.trim().length == 0 || regiao.trim().length == 0){
         //handle error
             M.toast({html: 'Preencha todos os campos!'})
      } else {


      var data ={
           name: nameBox.value,
           login: loginBox.value,
           sninv: sninvBox.value,
           numero: numeroBox.value,
           sndtl: sndtlBox.value,
           tele: teleBox.value,
           regiao: regiaoBox.value
     };

     google.script.run.appendData(data);
     }//CLOSE ELSE
    }//CLOSE ADD RECORD

    </script>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: "some of the items need multiple lines in the same cell. Is there anyway I can do that?" Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to know how to accept multiple lines in a form field, or allow the multiple lines to be inserted into Google Sheets. Would you please also outline the research that you have already done so that we don't double up on this.

Comment: Hi, I have added two images to show what I need to do, I never used java and script apps, I just did a research yesterday and started building this userform... In Excel VBA I had the same problem but the fix was easy,in the properties I just changed the option "EnterKeyBehavior" from False to True.

Comment: Java and Javascript are NOT the same thing - please choose one tag or the other. FWIW, Google Sheets scripts are based on Javascript but [use features from several versions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features). HOWEVER... this is not a question about Google Sheets, or Javascript (or Java, even) - your question is about html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` tag doesn't support line breaks. If you want to add a multi-line input, you have to use `<textarea>` instead. So you should change all the elements which could potentially have several lines from `<input>` to `<textarea>`.

That is, you should change these lines:

`<input id="sninv" type="text" class="validate">`

`<input id="numero" type="text" class="validate">`

`<input id="sndtl" type="text" class="validate">`

To these ones:

`<textarea id="sninv" type="text" class="validate"></textarea>`

`<textarea id="numero" type="text" class="validate"></textarea>`

`<textarea id="sndtl" type="text" class="validate"></textarea>`

This way, you can add multi-line text, which will still be a multi-line when you send it to the spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Hello @iamblichus! Thank you man, that is exactly what I wanted to do.